# Extracting the text from some HTML tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to webscrape job listings on a career page. I am having trouble just printing out the information I need.

This is was the HTML looks like

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
<a href="http://careers.steelseries.com/apply/3LXwyjYOrb/Customer-Experience-Specialist">
                                        Customer Experience Specialist                                    </a>
</h4>
<ul class="list-inline list-group-item-text">
<li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Chicago, IL</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>Operations</li>
</ul>
```

What I want it to print out is

```
Customer Experience Specialist
Chicago, IL
Operations
--------------
```

The code I tried is this:

```
section = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-xs-7 jobs-list')
for elem in section:
    wrappers = elem.find('ul').get_text()
    print(wrappers)
```

But what that does is print it for me with too many new lines and spaces as so:

```
                                        Customer Experience Specialist                                    


Chicago, IL
Operations
```

Keep in mind there are also like 4 empty lines above the job title and another new line after 'Operations'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sections = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-xs-7 jobs-list')
sections = [section for section in sections.split("\n") if section and section != " "]
print("\n".join(sections))
```

Regards!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I got the same thing

Comment: Could you `print(sections)` without the join, the next try will be the one ;)

Comment: I get this now `['\n\n\n\n                                        Customer Experience Specialist                                    \n\n\nChicago, IL\nOperations\n\n\n\n\n\n]` but with like a lot of spaces between the last \n and the first letter of Customer, Chicago, and Operations

Comment: Modified! try it again ^^

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help though! What happened was I needed an additional for loop to divide each listing and then from there I was able to use the `strip()` function. So it looks like this now `section = soup.find_all('div', class_='col col-xs-7 jobs-list')
for elem in section:
    wrappers = elem.find('ul')
    for x in wrappers:
        text = wrappers.find('li').get_text()
        print(text.strip())
        print("---")`

Answer (score 0):

After get_text() function add rstrip() to remove all trailing newlines .This removes all trailing whitespace, not just a single newline.

Otherwise, if there is only one line in the string S, use S.splitlines()[0].

Comment: The first method using rstrip() didn't change anything, and the second method caused it to not print anything out